# instead of icons it shows blank squares

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm doing a form with bootstrap and html, and i'm using glyphicons but for some reason those doesn't work

```
<label>Colaboración Internacional &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="font-size:24px;"></span>&nbsp;</label>
```

But it only appears something like a blank square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you import the Glyphicons libray in your page, best way to check is to inspect the span[image]

if you see some :before with content and code, it OK, if not you need to include it in your imports

Comment: How do i import the library? :(

Comment: Check if this can help: https://codepen.io/Memfis/pen/JpVVvM
@h0merr